# SELECT DISTINCT YEAR() with Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

If I have a Flask model like this:

```py
class Report(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
```

I want to get a list of the distinct years there are Reports for, for one User. So if the data was like this:

```
user_id |   date
--------------------
   1    | 2019-08-01
   1    | 2019-07-01
   1    | 2018-11-01
   1    | 2017-11-01
   2    | 2019-11-01
   2    | 2016-11-01
```

Then I want to get `[2017, 2018, 2019]` for User 1, something like this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date) AS year
FROM report
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY year ASC
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with Flask and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: This seems to be the one you are looking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110595/how-to-get-a-sql-alchemy-object-of-distinct-items-with-filter-on-related-objects?rq=1

Comment: @siopaoman No, that seems to be about selecting distinct items across two tables and have nothing to do with getting years from dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
query = session.query(extract('year', Report.date).label('year'))\
    .filter(Report.user_id == 1).distinct().order_by(asc('year'))
```

Which should work out to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(STRFTIME('%Y', report.date) AS INTEGER) AS year
FROM report
WHERE report.user_id = 1 ORDER BY year ASC
```

With the imports

```
from sqlalchemy import extract, asc
```

Comment: I'd just discovered `label()` but hadn't yet got as far as this - thanks! Does the job perfectly.